# Incorporate dow in batch file for /F statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, token

I have a windows batch file that calls another file, Services, that has a list of services and machines that need to restart, however one of these services doesn't need to start on the weekend.  Does anyone know how I could incorporate %dow% function in the Services file then call services based on dow ?  PS - it calls another batch file STOPANDWAIT which makes sure the services aren't already running.

here is my code:

```
:start_services
set SECTION=start_services
REM We will try to start all services
echo.
echo       ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo                  Starting services                             
echo       ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
%TIME_STAMP% BEFORE Starting services >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
REM Make sure the file that contains the services to be stopped and started actually exists
if not exist %SERVICES_FILE% (
    %TIME_STAMP% Services file not found. >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
    echo Services file not found.
    goto ERROR_FOUND
)

for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%i in (%SERVICES%) do (
    %TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
    @echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
    call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
    %TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
)


%TIME_STAMP% AFTER Starting services >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
if "%END_TAG%" == "start_services" goto PARTIAL_SUCCESS
```

My %SERVICES% file looks like this:

```
"EMSXComplianceService",\\bosxiptest
"Mxs.Xom",\\bosxiptest
"Mfs.Xom.Emsx",\\bosxiptest
"Mxs.Xom",\\bosxiptest
"Mxs.Xns",\\bosxiptest
"Mfs Wrangler Messanger",\\bosxiptest
```

and I do have a global %dow% where Wed is set for Wednesday etc.

Thank you in advance!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted to say what your `%dow%` looks like and a sample of your `%services%` file, so let's start guessing.

Try modifying the main loop in your procedure to this:

```
SET "runtoday="
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%i in (%SERVICES%) do IF "%%j%%k"=="" (
 if defined runtoday (
    %TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
    @echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
    call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
    %TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
 )
) ELSE (
 echo %%i|findstr "%dow%">nul
 if errorlevel 1 (set "runtoday=") else (set "runtoday=Y")
)
```

Then in your %SERVICES% file,

```
[Mon]
service1,runs,Monday
service2,runs,Monday
[Tue Fri]
service3,runs,Tuesday and Friday
service4,runs,Tuesday and Friday
```

where you daynames/digits/whatever are on a line that does **not** contain commas. I put them in brackets to make them obvious, following the style in a .INI file.

Note: If you set `runtoday` initially empty, the processes at the start of the file (up to the first [dayname] line) will **not** run. If you set it non-empty initially, then every line **will** run until a [dayname] line is encountered, turning the censorship on.

Comment: Hi @Magoo - thank you so much for helping.  I am failing when I run this and my batch says ELSE is not recognized as a valid command.  My services file is pretty simple, looks like this now:                                   [Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri]
"EMSXComplianceService",\\bosxiptest                         **where I have service, server**      This approach is very close to what I was hoping for, if I could just tweak it I will be done.  thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something  like 'SET MYDATE=%DATE:~0,3%' to get the current DOW.

Assuming your Services file is similar to:

```
ServiceName1,Machine1
ServiceName2,Machine2
```

Change the lines to:

```
ServiceName1,Machine1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
ServiceName2,Machine2,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
```

Your For loop would look something like this:

```
SET MYDATE=%DATE:~0,3%

for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 delims=," %%i in (C:\Temp\ServiceList.txt) do (
    ECHO Checking %%i on %%j

IF %MYDATE% == Mon (IF %%k == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

IF %MYDATE% == Tue (IF %%l == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

IF %MYDATE% == Wed (IF %%m == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

IF %MYDATE% == Thu (IF %%n == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

IF %MYDATE% == Fri (IF %%o == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

IF %MYDATE% == Sat (IF %%p == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

IF %MYDATE% == Sun (IF %%q == 1 (
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
))

)
```

Personally I would put

```
(
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i on %%j >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
@echo Calling StartServiceAndWait for %%i on %%j
call StartServiceAndWait %%j %%i
%TIME_STAMP% Starting %%i Done >> %TIMETRAC_FILE%
)
```

into a separate batch file and CALL it just so it's not repeated seven times in the batch file.

There's probably a cleaner way to do it, but this is what you get for posting a question on NYE.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `%date%` variable has the day embedded in it (this depends on regional **and** user settings) then try this:

```
set "skip="
echo %date%|find /i "sat" >nul && set skip=1
echo %date%|find /i "sun" >nul && set skip=1
if not defined skip (call "your batch file to change services.bat") else (goto :weekend)
```